# Grails 3.3.x with gradle 4.x does not work?

Tags: grails, gradle, grails-3.3

Grails 3.3.0 does not work with gradle 4.x is that right?

I have problems running intergation test (dependency injection does not work) when running them with gradle via `integrationTest` or `build` task.

BTW: Why isn't there a grails-3.0 tag?

Comment: There are several `grails-3.*` tags.

Comment: Ok, the search is there a bit lazy. I think, it would be a good idea to follow the same naming convention as for the grails-2.x tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Grails 3.3.0 does not work with gradle 4.x is that right?

It really depends on what you are doing, but there have been issues identified.  https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10713